# Bash: Find specific files and cut last 5 characters from name

Tags: bash, file-rename

I have some files under my `./` folder, for example:

```
$ ls
XX
AArse
BArse
CCCAArse
YY
....
```

After **some command** I want:

```
AA
BA
CCCAA
```

I.e. If the end of the filename contains `rse`, the file gets renamed (to remove `rse` from it's name).

How do I implement **some command** in bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `bash`:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for file in *rse; do
  mv -i "$file" "${file%rse}"
done
```

The shell option `nullglob` expands a non-matching glob pattern to a null string and the parameter expansion `${file%rse}` removes the shortest suffix `rse` from the filename.

Option `-i` prompts to overwrite already existing files.

Answer (score 3):

With Perl's standalone `rename` command, a regex and bash's globbing:

```
rename -n 's/...$//' *rse
```

In some distributions `rename` is also called `prename`. If everything looks fine, remove `-n`.

Answer (score 0):

To give a slightly more generic answer:

**finder.sh:**

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
usage() {
  echo 'Usage: ./finder.sh string_to_remove'
  exit
}

if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
  usage
fi

check_string=$1
counter=0
for file in ./*
do
  if [[ -f $file ]]; then
    if [[ $file == *"$check_string"* ]]; then
      mv -v "$file" `echo $file | sed "s/$check_string//"`
      let "counter++"
    fi
  fi
done

if [ ! "$counter" -gt 0 ]; then
  echo "No files found containing '$check_string'"
else
  echo "$counter files effected with string '$check_string'"
fi
```

You can then use this with different substrings in the following way (after doing a `chmod +x finder.sh`):

```
./finder.sh any_string
# Removes 'any_string' from all filenames
```

### Examples:

With the following directory listing:

```
$ ls
AArse  
AByfl  
BArse  
CCCAArse
XX
YY
```

you could run

```
./finder.sh rse; ./finder.sh yfl
```

to get the following output:

```
renamed './AArse' -> './AA'
renamed './BArse' -> './BA'
renamed './CCCAArse' -> './CCCAA'
3 files effected with string 'rse'
renamed './AByfl' -> './AB'
1 files effected with string 'yfl'
```

so that your directory now looks like:

```
AA
AB
BA  
CCCAA
XX
YY
```

Of course you might want to build in some checks for potential overwrites when using the `mv` command.